# How to time the CleanupMono function in Unity3d

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine, objective-c++

My Unity3D program is not exiting properly. It's sitting around in deadlock while trying to close, and this happens a lot. Is there a way to close down my player loop manually?

[image]

Comment: What are you doing that's causing that behavior? Can you reproduce the problem with a new, empty project?

Comment: I'm running a client dll that we've built to run alongside the game. If the problem keeps being this bad, then I probably will try to run a version of the app that has nothing but the dll. That might help me track down the issue.